# CollapseSidebar is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a script for a project, it has a function to collapse or open the sidebar on click on hamdurger icon but when I click it gives me error

> TypeError: this.CollapseSidebar is not a function

The following is my code:

```
(function($) {
    'use strict';
    var Prtm = {
        Constants: {
            LEFTMARGIN:'315px',
            COLLAPSELEFTMARGIN: '63px',
        },
        PrtmEle:{
            BODY: $('body'),
            SIDEBAR: $('.prtm-sidebar'),
            SIDENAV: $('.sidebar-nav'),
            MAIN: $('.prtm-main'),
            HEADER: $('.prtm-header'),
            CONTENTWRAP: $('.prtm-content-wrapper'),
            CONTENT: $('.prtm-content'),
            PRTMBLOCK: $('.prtm-block'),
            FOOTER: $('.prtm-footer'),
            HAMBURGER: $('.prtm-bars'),
        },
        Init:function(){
            this.BindEvents();
        },
        BindEvents:function(){
            this.PrtmEle.BODY.on('click',this.PrtmEle.HAMBURGER,function(){
                this.CollapseSidebar();
            });
        },
        CollapseSidebar: function(){
            this.PrtmEle.HAMBURGER.toggleClass("prtm-sidebar-closed is-active");
            this.PrtmEle.BODY.toggleClass("prtm-sidebar-closed is-active");
            this.PrtmEle.SIDEBAR.toggleClass('collapse');
        },
    };
    Prtm.Init();
})(jQuery);
```

When I change `this.CollapseSidebar` to `Prtm.CollapseSidebar` it works properly. What I am doing wrong here and how it can be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Why it do not work?* Because a *function()* binds its own *this*.

One thing you can do is to use [`Arrow function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which do not bind its own `this` - like this:

```
BindEvents:function(){
    this.PrtmEle.BODY.on('click',this.PrtmEle.HAMBURGER,() => {
        this.CollapseSidebar();
    });
}
```

Inside you *click function* `this` will refer to the `window` - so either you can create a temporary variable like the below or use the *arrow function*:

```
BindEvents:function() {
    let $this = this;
    this.PrtmEle.BODY.on('click',this.PrtmEle.HAMBURGER,function() {
        $this.CollapseSidebar();
    });
}
```

Comment: It works Thanks, but I really want to know what => means here and how it works.

Comment: that is called *arrow function* - works the same as `function(){` except that it do not give you `this` or `args` - have linked the doc above :)